# how to fire and forget in azure durable functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-durable-functions

I want to fire and forget in a nodejs durable orchestrator
a call to an activity

```
yield context.df.callActivity("Activity1", "name")
```

but I noticed that the orchestrator waits for this to complete I want to fire the activity and forget about it and proceed how can I achieve that in nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the `yield` from your statement to kick off the activity call and continue on without waiting for it to complete. An orchestrator only blocks when it encounters a `yield`. This is essentially what's being done in the fan-out/fan-in pattern, described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=javascript#fan-in-out).

```js
const df = require("durable-functions");

module.exports = df.orchestrator(function*(context) {
    const parallelTasks = [];

    // Get a list of N work items to process in parallel.
    const workBatch = yield context.df.callActivity("F1");
    for (let i = 0; i < workBatch.length; i++) {
        parallelTasks.push(context.df.callActivity("F2", workBatch[i]));
    }

    yield context.df.Task.all(parallelTasks);

    // Aggregate all N outputs and send the result to F3.
    const sum = parallelTasks.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
    yield context.df.callActivity("F3", sum);
});
```

In the example above, the invocations of `context.df.callActivity("F2", ...)` are being done in a "fire-and-forget" way, where we're adding the tasks to a list instead of `yield`ing them. The example only waits for them after the `for` loop in the call to `context.df.Task.all(...)`.

You can apply this pattern to have the orchestrator continue to take more steps before waiting for activities to complete. Note, however, that if you never eventually `yield` the tasks, then the orchestrator may complete but remain in a "Running" state. It will only transition into a "Completed" state after all the fire-and-forget tasks have completed.

Comment: This Probably Provides the best answer to my question and solved the problem ,Thanks a lot Gillum